How to control the CPU utilization of each process in a process group so that it does not exceed a certain limit?
I have a multi-process program, assuming there are 128 processes (exactly 128 logical cores in the system), each running the exact same task. I want to control the CPU utilization of each process to be 25%.
I tried using cgroup and set cpu.cfs_quota_us=3200000 at startup for this program, but this caused all processes to simultaneously sleep (cgroup's quota is exhausted) and start, which is not the behavior I want to see. I want these 128 processes to be independently managed in the scheduling system to evenly distribute the system load.
Even distribution includes two aspects: 1. Even load on each logical core; 2. Even load on the entire system over time.

It would help if you explained why you want to do that. I can understand tweaking things to avoid exceeding memory or disk IO bandwidth but not to set CPU utilisation to be some arbitrary fraction of what it could be (unless overheating is a problem).

"Even load on each logical core" AFAIK this is not possible. At least, this cannot be ensured. You might find a way for each process to be scheduled for a given time on each logical cores but one logical core can do far more operation than another depending on the target processor and the specific application code in a specific execution context. I think you should precisely define what "load" is supposed to mean.
